# HTML file upload type = "file" is also uploading from type = "text" input fields

Tags: html, image, file, upload

Here is my HTML code.  In the browser, I click on the text fields and a box shows for file input.  It is like I selected the type = "file" input field.  Why does my HTML code do this?

```
<div id = "section">
<form action = "receive.php" method = "post">
<!-- Image to upload -->
    <label for = "item"> Item: <input id = "item" type = "file" name = "items" accept = "image/*">
<!-- Text to enter -->
    <label for = "mail"> Email: <input id = "mail" type = "text" name = "email">
    <label for = "word"> Words: <input id = "word" type = "text" name = "words">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" name = "submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: No, the code you've posted doesn't do that. Do you have some sort of JavaScript plugin or browser extension that might be doing that?

Comment: @j08691: Actually, it does.

Comment: @SLaks - not for me in Chrome or IE (of all things) http://jsfiddle.net/c1d64qj7/

Answer (score 2):

You need to close your `<label>` tags.

Otherwise, your entire form is in the `<label>` for the upload control, and clicking on the label will click the control.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed your elements properly, most likely the `<label>` elements.

```html
<div id = "section">
<form action = "receive.php" method = "post">
<!-- Image to upload -->
    <label for = "item"> Item: <input id = "item" type = "file" name = "items" accept = "image/*"></label>
<!-- Text to enter -->
    <label for = "mail"> Email: <input id = "mail" type = "text" name = "email"></label>
    <label for = "word"> Words: <input id = "word" type = "text" name = "words"></label>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" name = "submit">
</form>
</div>
```